# LINQ, SelectMany with multiple possible outcomes

Tags: c#, linq

I have a situation where I have lists of objects that have to be merged. Each object in the list will have a property that explains *how* it should be treated in the merger. So assume the following..

```
enum Cascade {
  Full,
  Unique,
  Right,
  Left
}

class Note {
  int Id { get; set; }
  Cascade Cascade { get; set; }
  // lots of other data.
}

var list1 = new List<Note>{
 new Note {
   Id = 1,
   Cascade.Full,
   // data
 },
 new Note {
   Id = 2,
   Cascade.Right,
   // data
 }
};
var list2 = new List<Note>{
  new Note {
   Id = 1,
   Cascade.Left,
   // data
  }
};
var list3 = new List<Note>{
  new Note {
    Id = 1,
    Cascade.Unique,
    // data similar to list1.Note[0]
  }
}
```

So then, I'll have a method ...

```
Composite(this IList<IList<Note>> notes){
  return new List<Note> {
      notes.SelectMany(g => g).Where(g => g.Cascade == Cascade.All).ToList()
      // Here is the problem... 
      .SelectMany(g => g).Where(g => g.Cascade == Cascade.Right)
      .Select( // I want to do a _LastOrDefault_ )
      // continuing for the other cascades. 
  }
}
```

This is where I get lost. I need to do multiple `SelectMany` statements, but I don't know how to. But this is the **expected behavior**.

### `Cascade.Full`

The `Note` will be in the final collection no matter what.

### `Cascade.Unique`

The `Note` will be in the final collection one time, ignoring any duplicates.

### `Cascade.Left`

The `Note` will be in the final collection, **First** instances superseding subsequent instances. (So then, Notes 1, 2, 3 are identical. Note 1 gets pushed through)

### `Cascade.Right`

The `Note` will be in the final collection, **Last** instance superseding duplicates. (So Notes 1, 2, 3 are identical. Note 3 gets pushed trough)

Comment: I find it is often helpful to write code the "long" way when the LINQ way isn't immediately obvious. In doing so, you're able to sort through all the details and get a working solution. *Then* the LINQ version becomes easier to reason.

Comment: Is there any need to preserve the order of notes or are you just looking for the resulting list, no matter the order?

Comment: The _order_ does not matter, merely the existence of the proper notes in the _final_ compilation.

Comment: And it's a given that you don't have weird edge cases? Like 1, Unique / 1, Right (which one wins? Same for the other way around, 1, Left / 1, Unique? What about 1, Left / 1, Right?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should decompose the problem in smaller parts. For example, you can implement the cascade rules for an individual list in a seperate extension method. Here's my untested take at it:

```
public static IEnumerable<Note> ApplyCascades(this IEnumerable<Note> notes)
    {
        var uniques = new HashSet<Note>();
        Note rightToYield = null;
        foreach (var n in notes)
        {
            bool leftYielded = false;

            if (n.Cascade == Cascade.All) yield return n;
            if (n.Cascade == Cascade.Left && !leftYielded)
            {
                yield return n;
                leftYielded = true;
            }
            if (n.Cascade == Cascade.Right)
            {
                rightToYield = n;
            }
            if (n.Cascade == Cascade.Unique && !uniques.Contains(n))
            {
                yield return n;
                uniques.Add(n);
            } 
        }

        if (rightToYield != null) yield return rightToYield;
    } 
}
```

This method would allow to implement the original extension method something like this:

```
    List<Note> Composite(IList<IList<Note>> notes)
    {
        var result = from list in notes
                     from note in list.ApplyCascades()
                     select note;
        return result.ToList();

    }
```

Comment: Thats much better than using linq statements to solve this. But I think you need `if (n.Cascade == Cascade.Unique && !uniques.Add(n)))` instead

Comment: @Magnus thanks, fixed (needed to `Add` the notes to the HashSet)

Comment: Thanks, this works well enough. I am disappointed that it cannot be done in a single LINQ query, though.